Después de tomar una fotografía y regresar a mi aplicación pierde referencias de interfaces y controladores, y una parte grafica se queda en blanco
Tengo una aplicación de Android construida con Java, me esta ocurriendo un error mayormente en dispositivos de la marca Motorola, los modelos que tengo detectado en los que ocurre este problema en es los modelos  MOTO G51 y M0TO G31, y otros modelos de esta marca pero no es tan constante el problema, el comportamiento es el siguiente: se selecciona un campo en el que se hace el llamado a la cámara para tomar una fotografía, después de hacer la captura y confirmar, regresa a la aplicación y se hace el guardado de la fotografía en la carpeta de la aplicación, se guarda en la base de datos local, se sube a un servidor y se muestra la miniatura de la fotografía, el error se presenta al regresar de la cámara al intentar hacer el guardado en la base de datos me regresa el siguiente error:
2024-04-08 13:53:24.619 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.info_.ui.controllers.ControllerInfosync.saveAnswerInMemory(java.lang.String, byte[], java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at com.info_sync.views.DialogImages.onActivityResult(DialogImages.java:1089)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2905)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2885)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:392)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:351)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:647)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at com.info_sync.ui.GroupActivity.onActivityResult(GroupActivity.java:870)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8424)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5127)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4547)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4592)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2152)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2024-04-08 13:53:24.620 22148-22148/com.info_ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:970)

Se esta utilizando un objeto interfaz ya que este control de fotografías se utiliza en 2 niveles diferentes, por lo que existen 2 controladores para cada nivel, cuando se inicializa el objeto de la clase se le pasa el parámetro del controlador que se utilizara para el llamado de la función saveAnsweInMemory() pero por alguna razón al regresar de la cámara la referencia del controlador se pierde ya que se queda nula, al igual que varias consultas que se hacen al momento. lo que ocurre en mi aplicación es que se queda unos segundos detenida y al volverse a construir la parte grafica la parte de los campos se queda en blanco.
El error se presenta en esta línea de código:
mController.saveAnswerInMemory(mFieldId, jsonArray.toString().getBytes(), new JSONObject().toString(), true);

En este apartado es donde se le pasa la referencia del controlador que se esta manejando, así como otros parametros
 public void setDialogData(ImageView aPicture,
                              String aPictureName,
                              String aFieldId,
                              ControllerInfosync aController,
                              String geoLocation,
                              String creationAt,
                              String folio,
                              OnDismissListener callback){
        mPicture = aPicture;
        mFieldId = aFieldId;
        mController = aController;
        mRecordId = mController.getCurrentRecordId();
        mNumSet = mController.getNumSet();
        mGroupId = mController.getGroupId();
        mGeoLocation = geoLocation;
        mCreationAt = creationAt;
        this.folio = folio;
        this.onDismissListener = callback;
    }

Error en la app
He probado en distintos dispositivos y no se presenta el problema, solamente en los Motorola es un comportamiento más evidente, este se provoca más si empiezo abrir varias aplicaciones y dejo en segundo plano, por que en el uso empieza trabajando bien, pero parece que en un momento que el dispositivo esta más saturado es cuando empieza hacer ese comportamiento, al presentarse ese error muchos de los datos que se estaban manejando se van a null.

Dónde instancias ese mController?

Cuando construyo la vista los campos se agregan en un RecyclerView y en el viewHolder dependiendo del tipo creo el objeto de esta clase y a través de la función que puse "setDialogData" le paso estos parámetros  y dentro de ellos le estoy pasando el controlador

this.dialogImages = new DialogImages();

dialogImages.setDialogData( null, photoName, mFieldBase.getId(), mFieldBase.getController(), geoLocation, creationAt, folio, new DialogImages.OnDismissListener() { @Override public void onDismiss() { EventBus.getDefault().post( new MessageUpdateImageList( mFieldBase.getId(), getAdapterPosition() ) ); } } );

Perdón no te había mencionado @Benito-B
